# In Django1.10, sending email functionality not working without any exception

Tags: python, django, email

I would like to send email in Django 1.10.

This is the snippet code in settings.py file.

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my email address'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

This is the snippet code in views.py file which is responsible for sending  email.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings
from .forms import contactForm

def contact(request):
    form = contactForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']
        subject = 'Message form MYSITE.com'
        message = '%s %s' %(comment, name)
        emailFrom = form.cleaned_data['email']
        emailTo = [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER]
        send_mail(subject, message, emailFrom, emailTo, fail_silently=True)
    context = locals()
    template = "contact.html"
    return render(request,template,context)
```

When I clicked submit button, I only received **Review blocked sign-in attempt** - google email.

So I have set my email account as **Allow less secure apps: OFF**.

Then hit the submit button again, I haven't received any email without any exception. As if sending email functionality working - browser loading for a little while.

I'm not sure why I couldn't receive email.

When I change `fail_silently = False`, I get a error like this.

```
SMTPAuthenticationError at /contact/
```

> (534, '5.7.14 https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbtS\n5.7.14 Mr_jh-DUic292PQTLx5X6kZmxxN8WFLelRksUwF0nHxSUPVpU_fX3m7ds3VOoUuTxL9Gya\n5.7.14 bqnAiUAIf2Er2n31EXEHIOpy2Kqn9cFH-PsIJSx1GBn_SxygkjHWgZ9KWc9cxIAKTGQtru\n5.7.14 O3QBqKb6vCyVHCiN8wUY6jAVRdoRg9aK9BL5GTo6QKUomIilah549hrwMgvMcYrrKCLMGI\n5.7.14 YuEWvMHHPdW6TXkBB75UP2wxRZ9fI> Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 u2sm3991912edl.71 - gsmtp')

How can I handle it.

Comment: Have you created credentials and scopes in [google console](https://console.developers.google.com)?